# Is there a way to control which classes may access certain methods inside a class?

Tags: c#

I haven't really found an answer for this, so I'm curious if such a thing is even possible. Let's say I have a `DataClass` which holds all kinds of data for the program. Something like this, for example:

```
public class DataClass
{
    int Data_One;
    int Data_Two;
    int Data_Three;

    public int GetOne();
    public int GetTwo();
    public int GetThree();

    public void SetOne();
    public void SetTwo();
    public void SetThree();
}
```

Now, let's say I have two other classes, class `A` and class `B`, both are instanced once, and both isntances may have access to the same instance of `DataClass`. But what if I want the two classes to have different kind of access to `DataClass`?
 Let's say I want `A` to be able to read `Data_One`, and `Data_Two`, but only set `Data_One`, and have no access to `Data_Three`, whereas I want class `B` to be able to read and set `Data_Three` and `Data_Two`, but have no access to `Data_One`. Is this achieveable in some kind of way, and if so, what is the most convinient way to do it?

To further elaborate: In my example, there were 2 classes, but what I'm looking for is a general solution for any number of classes, that allows me to define which methods may be accessed by each class distinctly, regardless of how many other classes have access to the same method. Sort of like having an 'access table' that contains for each class which methods may be accessed by it. And I want this to be mantainable, so changing accessability permissions wouldn't be a hassle.

The most lifelike case would be having one class, that exclusively **sets** the data, a few others, that may only **read** that data, and the rest would have no access to it whatsoever. All this without having to use references between the classes, instad using a 'central' data object.

One idea I came up with was to typecheck the callers in the `DataClass` for every method, and determine whether or not that type has access to that method. The most ideal would be, if the `DataClass` would have some sort of `Access` method, that returns with an object or container-type with references to the accessible methods, although that sounds like too far of a stretch to me.

Comment: What would the point of this be?

Comment: You should overthink your class-design. Do you really want *one single* data-class? Or aren´t there many different types of data each servibg *one single* purpose? Obviously your dataclass has to many different properties that don´t belong together. Then you could easily have a reference to one of the parts within `A` and a reference to the other part within `B`. Anyway you could just define two interfaces on your class, one with the members that go to `A` and one with the members for `B`.

Comment: Well, there are a number of data that needs to be accessed by multiple classes that otherwise have no connection to each other, but they also need to access them with different privileges, some only able to read the same data that an other class could also set. And although in my example I used two such classes, but in general I'm looking for something that works with any number of classes, and still remains mantainable.

Answer (score 4):

Use interfaces. You can have

```
interface ICanBeUsedOnlyByA {
  int Data_One { get; set; }
}
interface ICanBeUsedOnlyByB {
  int Data_Two { get; set; }
}

class DataClass : ICanBeUsedOnlyByA, ICanBeUsedOnlyByB {

}
```

And then you have

```
class A {
   public ICanBeUsedOnlyByA A { get; set; }

    public A (ICanBeUsedOnlyByA a){
       A = a;
    }
}

class B {
   public ICanBeUsedOnlyByA B { get; set; }

    public B (ICanBeUsedOnlyByB b){
       B = b;
    }
}
```

And then `A` will have only access to `int Data_One;` and `B` to `int Data_Two;`
I advise you to read about interfaces and abstract classes.

Comment: The problem with this example is that I want some methods to be accessed by multiple classes, and some only accessed by a few (I used `A` and `B` here, but what I'm looking for is a method to apply the same rules to any number of classes, each of them having it's own accessability rules for `DataClass`. Simply using interfaces seems like an incomplete and rather complicated solution when working with numerous classes.

Comment: Then you have to provide more information in order to help you. What exactly do you want to do? It can be solved with different levels of complexity.

Comment: The example tells it all in my opinion. I have a class, that holds various data. And I have other classes (not neccessarily 2) that use and control this data. Some of the data may be accessed by multiple classes, but not neccessarily on the same level, some class may only read the same data that the other needs to be able to set. **Most** of the time, one class is the "setter" for the data, which exclusively modifies it, and the other one (or multiple ones) are the "getters" that only read, but not modify. Ideally, I also want to be able to modify accessibility for each class without hassle.

Comment: @MrLumie the detail is for you to work out. We can't work out all the complexities of your system in a few lines. Basically this is correct, use interfaces to control access. What interfaces are exposed to what classes is down to your implementation

Comment: This is what I call "Too much of a hassle". Imagine this example on a grand scale, with hundreds of fields, and dozens of classes accessing it. And make this system work by allowing yourself not just to be able to tell each class exactly what methods they are able to access, but also being able to simply change accessability rules at any point in development. Simply using interfaces just won't suffice at this point.

Comment: I suggest you address your complaint to [Grady Booch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grady_Booch)

Answer (score 1):

Basically interfaces:

```
public class DataClass : IAInterface, IBInterface
{
    int Data_One;
    int Data_Two;
    int Data_Three;

    public int GetOne();
    public int GetTwo();
    public int GetThree();

    public void SetOne();
    public void SetTwo();
    public void SetThree();
}

public class A
{
   public void SetA(IAInterface value)
   {
       //can only access whats in the interface
   }
}

public class B
{
   public void SetB(IBInterface value)
   {
       //can only access whats in the interface
   }
}

public interface IAInterface
{
    int GetOne();
    int GetTwo();
}

public interface IBInterface
{
    void SetOne();
    void SetTwo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can suggest in that case is to use `internal` for methods and properties to which you want restrict access and put one class to the other assembly. You also can use interfaces as it is suggested in other answers, but it is better to implement them explicitly in that case.

Comment: Thing is it turns into a huge hassle if applied on a grand scale (don't be msitaken by having 3 fields and 2 classes in the example, I'm looking for a method that allows the same for any number of classes / fields, without much of a hassle)